# tr1::regex Regular Expression throwing exception on a nested braces

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

My regular expression with a '}' is throwing exception when I use the microsoft tr1::regex.
But the same regex work fine with other regular expression interpreters.

Here is the simplified sample code.

```
string source = "{james}";
string exp = "{(.*)}";
std::tr1::cmatch res;
std::tr1::regex rx(exp);// Throws Exception here
while(std::tr1::regex_search(source.c_str(), res, rx))
{
    std::cout <<" "<< res[1]<<endl<<"....."<<endl;  
    source = res.suffix().str();
}
```

The same code works fine [here](http://regex101.com/r/hN6qR7).
What am I missing here?
I have tried escaping the '{', but that also doesn't work

```
string source = "\{james\}";
string exp = "\{(.*)\}";
```

I am using Visual studio 2010.

Thanks 
Sunil

Comment: Should be `string_exp = "\{(.*)\}"`. There are also cases where you might have to escape the back-slash as well depending on your `std::regex` constructor flags.  Also note that you can't have `string exp = string exp =...`  You cannot have spaces in variable names.

Comment: Different regexp engines have different behaviour, feature set and sometimes even some different symbols like the {} in the case of tr1. You always have to check when you switch between engines, there is no general standard. Pearl is a quasi standard, but it only brings some consitancy, its no rule for engine developers. Always read the docs of a new engine you work with.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` are RegEx metacharacters. They must be escaped.

Comment: Escaping also didn't work. Tried it like this. string source = "\{james\}";
string exp = "\{(.*)\}";

Comment: Don't escape the string. Do escape the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

In that regex, you need backslashes to escape those braces:

*\{*  *\}*

The *regex container is a string*, so the backslashes need to be part of that string.
To have backslashes in a string, which is *written in source code*, you need to escape them with... backslashes:

`"\\"` followed by `"{"`

So, try this:

```
string exp = "\\{(.*)\\}";
```

If you would have to feed that string through an additional parser, which also escapes with backslashes, then you gonna have to double the nuber of backslashes again.

You will need `"\\\\"` to match a backslash.